# How to start slcand and bring CAN interface up when hotplugging CAN dongle

Tags: android, udev, can-bus

I'm looking for a way on Android to start the [slcand](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/blob/master/slcand.c) daemon on the usb-serial (tty) device made available when plugging in a CANUSB dongle and bring up the network interface created by the `slcan` driver as a result.

I was thinking this could be accomplished easily enough by a `udev` script (I have access to the base Android image). But I discovered Android doesn't have any equivalent to that.

Is there any other Android application (in the base system) that receives `uevent`s which I could utilize (or extend) to handle this kind of use case?

For reference this is the `udevadm monitor --kernel --property` event log on a regular GNU/Linux desktop of plugging in said CANUSB dongle (first 4), followed by starting `slcand` (last 4, separated by a row of dashes):

```
KERNEL[767249.530132] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=bus/usb/001/020
DEVNUM=020
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=19
PRODUCT=403/ffa8/600
SEQNUM=2777
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[767249.531432] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=255/255/255
MODALIAS=usb:v0403pFFA8d0600dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFipFF
PRODUCT=403/ffa8/600
SEQNUM=2778
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[767249.531499] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/ttyUSB0 (usb-serial)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/ttyUSB0
SEQNUM=2779
SUBSYSTEM=usb-serial
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[767249.531767] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0 (tty)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=ttyUSB0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
MAJOR=188
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=2780
SUBSYSTEM=tty
UDEV_LOG=3
----------------------------------------------
KERNEL[767266.871139] add      /devices/virtual/net/slcan0 (net)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/net/slcan0
IFINDEX=32
INTERFACE=slcan0
SEQNUM=2781
SUBSYSTEM=net
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[767266.871189] add      /devices/virtual/net/slcan0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/net/slcan0/queues/rx-0
SEQNUM=2782
SUBSYSTEM=queues
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[767266.871214] add      /devices/virtual/net/slcan0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/net/slcan0/queues/tx-0
SEQNUM=2783
SUBSYSTEM=queues
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[767266.872198] move     /devices/virtual/net/can-aapje (net)
ACTION=move
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/net/can-aapje
DEVPATH_OLD=/devices/virtual/net/slcan0
IFINDEX=32
INTERFACE=can-aapje
SEQNUM=2784
SUBSYSTEM=net
UDEV_LOG=3
```

Comment: if you're going to downvote, please comment on _why_ otherwise I haven't got a clue what to do to improve....

Comment: Have you looked at this blog [entry](http://raulherbster.blogspot.de/2015/06/uevents-in-android-from-kernel-events.html)?